# C# event handing in single-threaded applications

Tags: c#, events

I have a single threaded C# assembly (my client) that subscribes to multiple events using the same event handler (a short print statement). The emitter of the events (the server) is multi-threaded and therefore could fire two events simultaneously at my single-threaded client.

How does the .NET platform handle this? Does it queue the events? Does it drop an event that can't be processed because the event handler is already busy?

**Background**

I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726684/) but judging by the clarification I needed to add I think I could do a much better job of abstracting my question to make it more general and useful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events in C# and .NET don't naturally know about threads *at all*. They're just an extra encapsulation layer for delegates, basically. The handlers will be called on whichever thread the "event raiser" chooses to use. It *could* decide to fire each event handler on a separate thread... or it could use one separate thread to calls *all* handlers, one after another... or it could do that synchronously within its own "normal" thread.